# Is this saying grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, idioms, verbs

Is the phrase *seat well and hold steadily* grammatically correct? If it is, why does it use *seat* instead of *sit*?

PS:the instruction will be used on the bus.

Comment: Supposition contrary to fact? Can you document this proverb?

Comment: @MetaEd: Since OP is looking for wording to display to bus passengers, he obviously doesn't mean "proverb". He means "standard phrasing" for such a context. Which I think is *way* too localised.

Comment: If a native English speaker saw a sign on a bus that read "seat well and hold steadily", they would laugh and know the sign was not written by a native speaker. Seating is just *not* something you do "well", nor is holding something you do "steadily".

Answer (score 2):

No, the saying is not formed according to normal grammar.  It should be

> **Sit** well and hold steadily.

*[Seat](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/seat)* can be a verb, but it is always transitive except in a few jargony cases.  Your example sounds like it's suffered a bad case of translation software syndrome.  A more natural-sounding (even idiomatic) version would be:

> [Sit tight](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/sit+tight) and hold steady.

Google confirms this with a respectable [5 separate occurrences](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=%22Sit%20tight%20and%20hold%20steady%22).

Comment: steady is adj， it will decorate hold。 why not use adv? thank you

Comment: Good catch, but *[steady](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/steady)* can be an adverb.

Answer (score 1):

No it isn't, and I can't think of any way it can be rescued.
Firstly, 'Seat' as opposed to 'sit' refers to placing something in a position where it will be stable.  The fitters on your bus might seat the benches well, but passengers would probably object to being glued down.  'Be seated' can refer to people, but only for the act of sitting down.

Secondly,  neither *sitting* nor *sitting down* can be done well or badly; they are simple actions, like blinking, which require no skill.

Thirdly, 'hold steadily'is almost certainly not what you mean. *Steadily* rather than *steady* would mean 'with an even pressure' (hat-tip to FumbleFingers for identifying the problem), and *hold* requires an object; if you mean 'hold something stable so you don't get thrown about', the usual phrase is *hold on*.

A sign saying "Remain seated and hold on tightly" would be good English (*tight* is more idiomatic but *tightly* is more formal and suitable for a sign); but do you really want to put it up?  If the bus is not jolting around, all it will do is downhearten or discourage the passengers, and if it is, they probably won't need instructions to hold on.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - it's not a "saying" but it's a perfectly a well-formed instruction.

To **seat well** in the context of, say, assembling something from a kit of parts would mean to make sure the relevant interlocking parts of two component are properly fitted together [(MW sense:3)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/seat).

In such a context, if the parts are to be permanently attached using glue, **hold steadily** would be a normal thing to do while waiting for the glue to set (and a normal way of expressing this).

In most contexts, *hold steady* would be more common, but personally I prefer *steadily* here. For reasons I can't quite put my finger on, it seems more suited to a context where the steady holding only needs to last for a relatively short period (until the glue sets enough to let go). I'd be glad to hear from anyone who has an opinion on this preference.

Comment: the proverb will be used on the bus.

Comment: @enjoylife: Crikey! You're not planning to fit out buses to operate in [Thailand](http://www.guardian.co.uk/uk/2011/sep/16/thailand-mothers-memory-sons), are you? In the UK, the standard wording is *"Please remain seated while the vehicle is in motion"*. I'm sure any mention of "holding on steadily" would have half the passengers jumping off the bus and looking for a more credible company to travel with!

Comment: ...anyway, in light of that information I'm afraid I have to vote to close.

Comment: IMHO, *steadily* emphasizes that it is an adverb, and so refers to the holding. *Steady* might refer to the object being held.  I can't really think of a situation where the two are opposed, but possibly if you tried to hold your girlfriend steady on the bus, you might not hold her steadily.

Comment: @TimLymington: ty. OP's actual request looks like a busted flush, but I really was interested in this particular point arising [from my misinterpretation]. One of the things I love about ELU is when someone else clarifies the "subconscious reasoning" or whatever it is that causes us to be relatively consistent in our choice of words. I suppose it really is just "idiom" quite often (in the sense of *that's what you hear, so that's what you repeat*), but doubtless there is often a genuine rationale behind the scenes causing one version to gain traction over others.

Comment: As an American, I definitely prefer *steady.* But we like adverbing adjectives.

Comment: @Peter Shor: By *"adverbing adjectives"* I take it you mean *using an adjective as an adverb*. It seems to me that implies you couldn't easily differentiate Tim's example (holding girlfriend *steady* so she doesn't topple, as opposed to *steadily* implying continously, possibly the sake of extended close physical contact even if the ride wasn't particularly bumpy). In general I'm all for "reductionism", but I think that type of distinction (although maybe a bit contrived here) is potentially available with many words in many contexts, so I'd prefer to hang on to it.

Answer (score 0):

***Seat*** as a verb intransitive is used in the sense of ' to occupy a seat' in the public transport field.

Therefore, it is more of a domain specific usage of the word and is appropriate in context.

Comment: Not in my experience: do you have some authority?

Comment: I have mentioned this from observed personal experience. Not in the US, though.